# Image is not displaying inside JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, java-2d

I want to display an image inside a panel. So I pass the path of the image to this method, open image file and pass it to the method of a private class dedicated to draw image inside the panel. The problem is the panel remains empty all the time and doesn't display anything.

Here is the code:

```
JPanel ImagePane; // I want to add image to this

public void getImagePath(String Path)
{       
    BufferedImage image = null;

    try 
    {
        image=ImageIO.read(new File(Path));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DisplayImage display= new DisplayImage();
    display.getImage(image);
}

private class DisplayImage extends JPanel
{
    private BufferedImage image=null;

    public void getImage(BufferedImage im)
    {
        image=im;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth() /2, image.getHeight()/2,ImagePane);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paintComponents` is a method of the `Container` which is used to paint each of the components in the container. Instead you need `paintComponent` to paint this single component.

Change your

```
public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
```

method to

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth() /2, image.getHeight()/2,ImagePane);
}
```

Notice the use of the `@Override` annotation to help with method signature checking.

Also calling

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

will update child components.

---

In your method `getImagePath` you don't appear to add the `DisplayImage` to any container. Instead you create a local `DisplayImage`, but don't use it.

Comment: Could be a size issue. What is the layout of the parent container of your `DisplayImage`?

Comment: In your method `getImagePath` you don't appear to add the `DisplayImage` to any container...

Comment: When I add `image` to panel, it says add a container. What should I add then?

Comment: You then need to add the panel to your container. Would look _something like_ `add(display);`. As you're using `GroupLayout` this will not be the exact syntax. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Actually I am learning Windows Builder. So I already created a JPanel there to which I want to add this image.

Answer (score 3):

You have to override [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

But in your code you are creating `public void paintComponents(Graphics g)` which is not correct

Answer (score 2):

There's the use of `@Override` annotation. If you make it a practice to use it whenever you're overriding a method, this issue can be resolved at compile-time. You need to use this:

```
    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```